# Mathematica: How to Parametric Plot a function in several time intervals using solutions of set of time dependent equations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have set of time dependent equations. 4 equations with 4 time dependent variables `{r[t], c[t], Uo[t], U1[t]}`.
Those 4 variables need to be used for a parametric transformation function 
`zJouko[o_] := r[t]*Exp[o*I] + (Uo[t]/(Exp[o*I] - c[t])) + U1[t]`. `o` has nothing to do with the time parameter. 
I need to plot this parametric function `zJouko[o]` for few time intervals on the same figure.
I have initial conditions for the 4 variables.

I have tried to use `NSolve` and then use its results to the plot but unsuccessfully.

Another problem is that when I launch Mathematica `NSolve` is working for several times and after that return empty solution.

I have tried this code unsuccessfully. I also don't know where to put the time intervals in the code.

some constants:

```
q2 = 0.5; mu1 = 1; mu2 = 1; tau = 1.0;
```

NSolve with the 4 equations and initial conditions

```
setEquation = NSolve[
{Uo[t]/c[t] == U1[t], 
q2 == (r[t]/c[t]) + (Uo[t]*c[t]/(1 - ((c[t])^2))) + U1[t],
mu1*Exp[-t/tau] == r[t]*(r[t] - (Uo[t]/((c[t])^2))),
mu2*Exp[-t/tau] == 
Uo[t]*(((Uo[t])/((((c[t])^2) - 1)^2)) - r[t]/((c[t])^2)),
r[0] == 1/100, Uo[0] == -1/2, U1[0] == -5/12, c[0] == 6/5}, {r[t], 
c[t], Uo[t], U1[t]}]
```

the function and the ParametricPlot:

```
zJouko[o_] := r[t]*Exp[o*I] + (Uo[t]/(Exp[o*I] - c[t])) + U1[t];
ParametricPlot[{Re[zJouko[o]], Im[zJouko[o]]}, {o, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In a fresh start of Mathematica I give it

```
q2 = 1/2; mu1 = 1; mu2 = 1; tau = 1;
setEquation = Reduce[{Uo[t]/c[t] == U1[t], 
q2 == (r[t]/c[t]) + (Uo[t]*c[t]/(1 - ((c[t])^2))) + U1[t],
mu1*Exp[-t/tau] == r[t]*(r[t] - (Uo[t]/((c[t])^2))),
mu2*Exp[-t/tau] == Uo[t]*(((Uo[t])/((((c[t])^2) - 1)^2)) - r[t]/((c[t])^2)),
r[0] == 1/100, Uo[0] == -1/2, U1[0] == -5/12, c[0] == 6/5},
{r[t], c[t], Uo[t], U1[t]}]
```

and it tells me `r[t]` is either plus or minus `Sqrt[16 + E^t]/(4*Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[E^t])` and then given that choice of `r[t]`

```
c[t] == 4*r[t]
Uo[t] == r[t] - 16*r[t]^3
U1[t] == (1 - 16*r[t]^2)/4
```

Test the solution to see if it is correct.

```
q2 = 1/2; mu1 = 1; mu2 = 1; tau = 1;
r[t_]:=Sqrt[16 + E^t]/(4*Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[E^t]);
c[t_]:= 4*r[t];
Uo[t_]:=r[t] - 16*r[t]^3;
U1[t_]:= (1 - 16*r[t]^2)/4;
Simplify[ {Uo[t]/c[t] == U1[t], 
  q2 == (r[t]/c[t]) + (Uo[t]*c[t]/(1 - ((c[t])^2))) + U1[t],
  mu1*Exp[-t/tau] == r[t]*(r[t] - (Uo[t]/((c[t])^2))),
  mu2*Exp[-t/tau] == Uo[t]*(((Uo[t])/((((c[t])^2) - 1)^2)) - r[t]/((c[t])^2))}]
```

and this returns

```
{True, True, True, True}
```

Check your conditions at `t==0`

```
{r[0],c[0],Uo[0],U1[0]}//N
```

and it returns

```
{0.728869, 2.91548, -5.46651, -1.875}
```

Plot your function

```
zJouko[o_]:= r[t]*Exp[o*I] + (Uo[t]/(Exp[o*I] - c[t])) + U1[t];
Plot[Table[{Re[zJouko[o]], Im[zJouko[o]]},{t,0,2}], {o, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Please try to check all this carefully and see if you can find that I have made a mistake anywhere.

Comment: Reduce[ ] gave me an error results and below many numbers which I don't understand.

Comment: First of all, Reduce[ ] gave me an error results and below many numbers which I don't understand. Let's assume that NSolve[ ] or Reduce[ ] solve this system, How do I Plot this transformation for different times? for example plot zJouko[o_] for {o,0,2Pi} when t=0, plot for {o,0,2Pi} when t=1, plot for {o,0,2Pi} when t=2, and so forth. All on the same graph.